# React Redux and server side OAuth 2

Tags: api, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a React Redux application with a Node back end for my API's (also using Thunk). One of the API's I a connecting to is Strava, which requires OAuth authentication.

The Strava npm module I am using in the back end has an OAuth feature so it makes it pretty simple.

I have a "Connect to Strava" link on the app which sends a request to the API via my Node back end and sends back the Strava OAuth URL:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClickAuth: () => {
      store.dispatch(getStravaOauthUrl())
    }
  }
}
```

When clicking the link to connect to Strava (as per above), Node sends back a generated URL:

```
    //action    
    export const getStravaOauthUrl = () => {
          return function(dispatch) {
            dispatch(loadStravaBegin())
            return FitnessApi.fetchStravaOauthUrl().then(strava => {
              dispatch(receivedStravaOauthUrl(strava));
            }).catch(error => {
              throw(error);
            })
          }
        }
export const receivedStravaOauthUrl = (response) => {
  return{
    type: 'RECEIVED_STRAVA_OAUTH_URL',
    response,
    receivedAt: Date.now()
  }
}


    //reducer
    export const fitnessReducer = (state = {
      fitness: {},
      isFetching: true
    }, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'RECEIVED_STRAVA_OAUTH_URL':
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            fitness: {
              oAuthUrl: action.response,
              isFetching: false
            }
          });
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

So I have the response in my Store. My question is, how do I go about directing the browser to the URL and getting the response? I am not sure if it's best to use native JS redirect or make use of some sort of established process by using React Router?

I have seen a lot of what look like client side OAuth modules, but don't know if they'll be useful in my situation.

Thanks

Comment: Currently on the same path you are on. It depends on many things. For me, it depends on the version of React-Router. I’m on V4 and many of the online materials are for previous versions. Do you have server-side rendering?

Comment: I'm also on V4 React Router. I ended up not using React to route the user, and used window.location to direct the user to the OAuth URL right at the start of my render function if the OAuthUrl property exists. The OAuth prop would exist at a point in time on the Redux store when the URL was successfully received.